# How to find out if C++ memory was allocated with scalar new or array new

Tags: c++, new-operator, smart-pointers, delete-operator

I am working on optimizing my smart pointer in my C++ library. The pointer has, besides from the built-in pointer and reference count, a boolean stating whether the pointer is scalar or array (i.e. it was allocated with new or new[] operator). The destructor of the class then uses this boolean the figure out which type of deallocation to perform (delete or delete[], respectively).

Specifying this boolean manually seems a little weird, so I was wondering, if there is a way to do this implicitly.

Full code on [Github](https://github.com/Gubbi69/WCL/blob/Main/WCL-1.0/Include/Storage/Pointer.h).

Comment: *so I was wondering, if there is a way to do this implicitly.* There is not.  This is why the smart pointers in the standard library use `smart_pointer<T>` and `smart_pointer<T[]>` to differentiate a single object from an array.

Comment: Why not do what `std::unique_ptr` does and add a specialization for `my_smart_ptr<T[]>`??? (see version (2) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr ) Alternatively you could add another template parameter which could be a deleter type or a non-type template parameter...

Comment: @fabian I'm not fully understanding you. I have never used such syntax : `T[]` as a typename. Would you please provide an answer with some code on how to maybe implement this functionality?

Comment: @Justaprogrammer [The page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) gives a full example.  Also your `Pointer` class seems to be a reinvention of what already exists, `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: There's no *portable* way to do this.  There might be hackish ways that would work for certain compilers and runtime environments, but trying to exploit them would be very much asking for trouble, as the code would break when you tried to use it in some other environment (including potentially even just future releases of the same compiler)

Comment: The compiler doesn't know.  That's why we have `delete` and `delete[]` (and that's why the onus is on the programmer to use the right one).  Doing things this way avoids unnecessary overhead, a common theme in C++